# Character set in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, character-encoding

I've run this code in MySQL, and it's succeeded. But when I run it in SQL Server 2005, this error occurred:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'DEFAULT'

This is the code:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Anyone can explain why it couldn't run successfully in SQL Server 2005.
Thanks and sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support the "default character set" on the "create database" statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061(v=SQL.90).aspx